# Erro ao passar um vetor de objetos em C++

Tags: c++, array

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
int verticeEstimativaMinima(Node *grafo, int numVertices){}
```

E em minha função `main`, tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
Node *grafo = new Node[numVertices];
```

Ou seja, basicamente, estou tentando passar um vetor de objetos para uma função.
Estou chamando-a dessa maneira:

```
verticeEstimativaMinima(grafo,numVertices);
```

Mas o compilador me retorna:

> [Error] could not convert 'grafo' from 'Node*' to 'Node'

Comment: http://ideone.com/LWENYQ Deu tudo certo. Você precisa colocar um código mais completo. O erro não está nas partes que você postou.

Comment: Desculpe, o erro estava listando na linha errada do compilador, foi falha minha mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As informações que você passou não estão esclarecendo a causa de seu erro.
O trecho de código abaixo compila e executa corretamente [online](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php).

```
struct Node
{
    char c;
    int i;
};

int verticeEstimativaMinima(Node * grafo, int numVertices){ return 0;}

int main()
{    
   Node *grafo = new Node[4];
   verticeEstimativaMinima ( grafo, 4);   
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;    
   return 0;
}
```